# Function to generate all subsets of size n

Tags: c#, beginner, algorithm, combinatorics

The function works this way:

1. `Set` is an instance variable, and is an array of type generic.
2. `nElement` is the size of all the subsets that you want. For example if you give it the value 3 the function will return all the subsets of `Set` of size 3
3. The idea is that we create an array named `indices` (indices = index in French) that will follow the index that we want for each subset.
4. We know that all of our subsets have a size of 3 elements so if `indices[2]` = 3 we have to increment `indices[1]` by 1 and set all of the following `indices[i]` to `indices[i-1]+1`.

### Example

`Set = {1,2,3,4} nElement = 3`

1. for the first subset the `indices = {0,1,2} -> {1,2,3}`
2. for the second subset the `indices = {0,1,3} -> {1,2,4} indices[2] = 3` so we `indices[1]++` and `indices[2] = indices[1]+1`
3. for the third subset the `indices = {0,2,3} -> {1,3,4} indices[2] = indices[2] = 3` so we `indices[1]++` and `indices[2] = indices[1]+1` but `indices[1]` now `= 2` and the max value that `indices[1]` can have is 2 so `indices[0]++` and `indices[1] = indices[0]+1`
4. for the fourth subset the `indices = {1,2,3} -> {2,3,4}`

### Code

```
public List<T[]> GenerateCoupleOf(int nElement)
{
    if (nElement < 1)
        throw new Exception("nElement must be greater than 0");

    List<T[]> tr = new List<T[]>();
    T[] arr;

    int[] indices = new int[nElement];
    T[] temp_arr = new T[nElement];

    for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
        indices[i] = i;

    while (indices[0] <= Set.Length - 1 - ((Set.Length - 1) - (Set.Length - 1 - indices.Length + 0)) + 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
            temp_arr[i] = Set[indices[i]];

        arr = new T[nElement];

        for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = Set[indices[i]];

        tr.Add(arr);

        indices[indices.Length - 1]++;

        for (int i = indices.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (indices[i] > Set.Length - 1 - ((Set.Length - 1) - (Set.Length - 1 - indices.Length + i)) + 1)
            {
                indices[i - 1]++;
                for (int j = i; j < indices.Length; j++)
                    indices[j] = indices[j - 1] + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return tr;
}
```

Comment: Do you really call the method `GenerateCoupleOf`? Why don't post the entire class? The code is extremely hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

**Readability** is a big factor in programming when it comes to maintaining the code by yourself or some other developer.
Readability can be improved by using standards which other developers expecting to see. Therefor some guidelines had been created like the [`.NET Naming Guidelines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) to name things like classes, properties, variables and parameters. Based on these guidlines variables should be named using `camelCase` casing instead of `snake_case` casing.

**Omitting braces** `{}` can lead to hidden and therfor hard to find bugs. i would like to encourage you to always use them.

That beeing said I will first focus on one part of your code...no, on two parts of your code but both are related.

> ```
> while (indices[0] <= Set.Length - 1 - ((Set.Length - 1) - (Set.Length - 1 - indices.Length + 0)) + 1)
> ```

and

> ```
> if (indices[i] > Set.Length - 1 - ((Set.Length - 1) - (Set.Length - 1 - indices.Length + i)) + 1)
> ```

but lets focus on the right part of the first line

```
Set.Length - 1 - ((Set.Length - 1) - (Set.Length - 1 - indices.Length + 0)) + 1
```

using simple math we can shorten this by removing the first `()` like so

```
Set.Length - 1 - (Set.Length - 1 - Set.Length + 1 + indices.Length - 0) + 1
```

and by removing the remaining `()` like so

```
Set.Length - 1 - Set.Length + 1 + Set.Length - 1 - indices.Length + 0 + 1
```

we get

```
Set.Length - indices.Length + 0
```

which is just

```
Set.Length - nElement + 0
```

which makes the `while` much more readable like so

```
int maxValueOfFirstIndex = Set.Length - nElement;

while (indices[0] <= maxValueOfFirstIndex)
{

}
```

which can be applied to the former `if` condition like so

```
if (indices[i] > maxValueOfFirstIndex  + i)
{

}
```

but `nElement` isn't as expressive as it could so `numberOfItems` could be a better name.

---

- The `T[] temp_arr` isn't used in a useful way. You can safely remove it.
- The check for `nElement < 1` whouldn't throw an `Exception` but an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
- because variables should be declared as near as possible to their usage you should move the declaration of `T[] arr` inside the `while`.
- by using `Enumerable.Repeat().Select().ToArray()` you can simplify the creation of `indeces[]` like so

  ```
  int[] indices = Enumerable.Repeat(0, nElement).Select((s, d) => s + d).ToArray();
  ```
- creating the `T[] arr` by a method would clean the main method as well
- using the `var` type instead of concrete types can help if you later need to refactor to use a different type. And its shorter to write hence easier to read, at least if the type can be seen clearly from the right hand side of the assignment.

  ---

Applying the mentioned points will lead to

```
public List<T[]> GenerateCoupleOf(int numberOfItems)
{
    if (numberOfItems < 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("numberOfItems", "Value must be greater than 0");
    }

    var tr = new List<T[]>();

    var indices = Enumerable.Repeat(0, numberOfItems).Select((s, d) => s + d).ToArray();

    var maxValueOfFirstIndex = Set.Length - numberOfItems;

    while (indices[0] <= maxValueOfFirstIndex)
    {

        T[] arr = CreateArrayByIndices(indices, numberOfItems);

        tr.Add(arr);

        indices[indices.Length - 1]++;

        for (var i = indices.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (indices[i] > maxValueOfFirstIndex + i)
            {
                indices[i - 1]++;
                for (var j = i; j < indices.Length; j++)
                {
                    indices[j] = indices[j - 1] + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return tr;
}
private T[] CreateArrayByIndices(int[] indices, int numberOfItems)
{

    var arr = new T[numberOfItems];

    for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = Set[indices[i]];
    }
    return arr;
}
```